# Hilios jQuery "The Final Countdown" Text After Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

So, I am using Hilios jQuery "The Final Countdown", and I want to add a "Text After Countdown". To make it even better to understand what I want: when the countdown finishes (when the date comes), I don't want it to show 00:00:00:00 or something like that, but to change to text (from 00:00:00:00 to something like "Server Started"). I am no good at this jQuery/Javascript etc. stuff, so can someone help me?

I am using his "Timezone Aware" function/add-on, too.

Comment: There is not much to show, everything is exactly as in his website which you can find here: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/timezone-aware.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one thing, the outer `if` is useless, because the finish event will be dispatched when the given date is already finished.

Other improvement is to register both `update` and `finish` as callbacks, the way above you are executing two `finish` events in a row, use this instead:

```
$('#clock').countdown(serverStart.toDate())
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'));
})
.on('finish.countdown',function(event) {
    $(this).html("Server Started");
});
```

Thank for using the plugin!

Comment: Hello, is it possible in addition to start a time limited countup after countdown ?

Answer (score 0):

As given in the documentation (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#introduction)

You can use jQuery's on method for "finish.countdown" event to execute your code.

```
$('div#clock').countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', callback)
    .on('finish.countdown', callback);
```

Here is JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/0yq3hbd2/1/

So in your case, it will be:

```
var currTime = new Date();

if (serverStart.toDate() < currTime)
    $('#clock').html("Server Started");
else
{
    $('#clock').countdown(serverStart.toDate(), function(event) { 
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S')); })
    .on('finish.countdown',function(event){$(this).html("Server Started");});
}
```

Comment: Well, as I said, I am not good at this jQuery etc. stuff .. :/  This is my current code, what am I doing wrong/how do I integrate into this?
**var serverStart = moment.tz("2015-07-31 22:55", "Europe/Vilnius");

$('#clock').countdown(serverStart.toDate(), function(event) {
$(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'));
});**

Comment: It still doesn't work ... I only have in my index.html file **jQuery.js**, his **jquery.countdown.min.js**, **moment-with-locales.min.js** and **moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js** (moment put in as shown in his example for localized time etc.). I put in what you are written and it doesn't work, still shows **00:00:00:00** ...

Comment: That is because the date you are giving (serverStart) is already past your current time. Give future time like: var serverStart = moment.tz("2015-08-01 00:55", "Europe/Vilnius");

Comment: Well, that's what I want - that when the time is past the current time, it will still show "server started" (for example, the date in there is 2015-08-15 00:00, it is 2015-09-20 or something and it still shows "Server started").